# How do I download Vim-Plug?

Tags: plugin-system

I'm trying to download Vim-Plug from here: https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug/wiki/tutorial

It says that I should "download a single VimScript file" and links to this https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim but to me that just looks like a text file. Do I download that text file? And save it as what?

Any advice would be so appreciated. I know this is probably very simple and easy, but I'm so confused and it's frustrating. Thank you!

Comment: Yes it's just a text file. What O.S. are you on? If you're on Windows you can use the Powershell instructions on the vim-plug page...

Comment: I'm using Windows 10. I'll look into powershell- thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right below the section you quote are the commands to download & install the file for both Vim and Neovim:

```
# Vim (~/.vim/autoload)
curl -fLo ~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim --create-dirs \
    https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim

# Neovim (~/.local/share/nvim/site/autoload)
curl -fLo ~/.local/share/nvim/site/autoload/plug.vim --create-dirs \
    https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim
```

In other words, yes, you download the text file, and put it in the appropriate directory, based on whether you are using Vim or Neovim.